# EDS.Notifications.YouDoNotHaveTheNecessaryAccessRights

Tags: exm

I have successfully been able to create a new automated email campaign and activated as well. The newly created email campaign is also listed in the dashboard list in the Automated link under Email Campaign.

Now when I click on "Domains" link form "Email Delivery Service" (Right panel) under "Administrator", I am getting below message in the popup message box.

> EDS.Notifications.YouDoNotHaveTheNecessaryAccessRights

[image]

Sitecore 9.3

Comment: Did you got any update we are facing same issue in sitecore 9.2 When we access from inside the server it is showing different error [Sitecore MTA is not current provider] but when accessing from outside of the server we are getting exact same issue you are facing related to access rights mentioned in screenshot.

Comment: Any update for this question? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: did you manage to get a resolution on this @arvind